# ¿Cómo puedo importar base de datos MySQL a servidor con Linux mediante Secure Shell Client?

Tags: mysql, linux, servidor, ssh

Hola a toda la comunidad Stack OverFlow, pido de su ayuda para poder importar mi base de datos a un servidor con Linux mediante SSH, tengo problemas, no sé realmente ya que hacer. Agradezco su tiempo por la ayuda.

Comment: por favor lee [ask] y añade esos **problemas** que mencionas tener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sería de utilidad que pusieras lo que haz hecho.

Pero el procedimiento es algo de este estilo.

```
mysqldump -h <hostname> -u<usuario> -p<contrasena> <dbfuente> | ssh host_remoto "mysql -h <hostname> -u <usuario> -p<contrasena de db2> <dbdestino>"
```

O podrías hacer algo semejante dentro de la máquina donde quieres hacer la migración.

```
mysql <nueva db> < <(ssh host_remoto "mysqldump -h <hostname> -u<usuario> -p<contrasena> <dbfuente>")
```

O podrías usar hacer un port forwarding.

Es decir. En tu servidor **a donde vas a importar tu base de datos**.

```
$ ssh -N -f -L <puerto1>:127.0.0.1:3306 <host donde esta tu dbactual>
$ mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 --port=<puerto1> -u <usuario1> --password=<contrasena1> dbactual | mysql -h <host donde está tu nueva db> -u <usuario2> --password=<contrasena2> tunuevadb
```

P.D. La segunda opción no la he intentado ;), así que si te funciona, me avisas.

Comment: podrías ayudarme con la parte de **port forwarding**, es que soy nuevo en todo éste tema, te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: Te sugiero que investigues lo que es un **port forwarding**, hay muchos recursos en la red. Busques ejemplos, intentes hacer uno con algún servidor remoto, digamos, que corras un servicio sencillo con nc, un servidor web, una base de datos, etc., y trates de hacerlo. No te preocupes si no te sale a la primera pues, si te llega a pasar, vuelves a preguntar con los tags (ssh, linux, etc), y seguramente estaré comentando.

Comment: Por cierto, si te sirvió mi respuesta, sería agradable :) que la puntuaras o, en caso contrario, explicaras lo que no te satisfizo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @mrc_es, me fue de gran ayuda y además son temas que no conocía y bueno ahora tengo noción de ellos, al igual te comparto un vídeo en el cual también me apoyé, **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F92DNU6XwKY**, gracias.

Comment: Nunca olvides consultar la documentación oficial. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta, de verdad me ha sido de gran ayuda tus post, @mrc_es.